# Ищу хорошие курсы по python для новичка

Tags: python

Кто знает курсы в Спб или онлайн по программированию для новичка?

Comment: Еще на stepik.org была пара курсов. Можно бесплатно пройти, еще сертификат в pdf выдадут

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо!